# What will do this lambda function to help sorting the list? and where will it get the argument element?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I'm new in this programming field and I'm trying to learn new concepts, in an exercise that was sent to us to practice at my university they made a test file to test some functions one of them had a lambda function I did some research about it and understood what they are but here I don't see where it take the argument that it needs and also how it helps to sort the list. sorry if this so basic here it is the code.

```
periodic_table_list = make_periodic_table()
assert isinstance(periodic_table_list, list), \
    "make_periodic_table function must return a list:" \
    f" expected a list but found a {type(periodic_table_list)}"

# Create a key function that will be used by the sorted method.
by_name = lambda element: element[NAME_INDEX]

# Sort the periodic table by the element names.
periodic_table_list = sorted(periodic_table_list, key=by_name)
```

I want to know where that lambda function gets that argument element, I know that it will help me sort the list by the element but where it'll get that argument from?

I was looking for documentation to understand what where done there and also I expected that somewhere there an argument where sent to the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are shorthand ways for creating functions, with the purpose of reducing boilerplate for one-liner functions. These two ways of defining `by_name` would be functionally equivalent.

```
by_name = lambda element: element[NAME_INDEX]
```

```
def by_name(element):
    return element[NAME_INDEX]
```

The `sorted` method can accept an argument called `key` which is a function that is called for each item in the iterable being sorted. The purpose is to transform a complex element of a list into a form that can be easily compared against. In this case it will sort based on the value in `NAME_INDEX` for each item in `periodic_table_list`